# android map not display

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on integrating **google maps** into my android app.

It was working fine.

However, after some days my map is not displaying and I don't know why?

Can anybody suggest me why?

I had not changed anything in my code.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey=""/>
```

Comment: Is Internet worked on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just generate a new key and use it again in your xml. It *should* fix your problem.

Comment: @Sri : u mean i want to repeat like the first how i generated the api key?

Comment: @Selva : excatly, bcoz ur keystore file may be generated newly. So try the same steps and get a new key.

Answer (score 1):

Did you refreshed your android debug key? This happens when you change the work environment or just delete .android folder from disk. Try creating the new key for maps. 
For your ease here is the command:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\bin>keytool.exe -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\User.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android

Answer (score 0):

Generate and Add you own key

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="Your Maps API Key goes here"
/>
```

Go throught these links,hope it helps you

[link for maps intro](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview)

[link to Generate key for map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey)